# Can you configure JPA to use a UUID for @Version in optimistic concurrency

Tags: java, jpa, optimistic-concurrency

Is there a way to configure or override the JPA @Version annotation to use Strings (UUID's) ?

I have a simple example of optimistic concurrency working using int as per examples

```
int version

@Version
Public Integer getVersion ()
    return version;
...
```

We have a requirement to look at using GUID's for versioning instead (at the moment held in a Postgres db as a character varying 100).

I'll be honest I've got my example working a short while ago and haven't dug around too much yet.  My first attempt was a bit of a hopeful shot in the dark -

```
String version

@Version @GeneraedValue(generator="system-uuid")
Public String getVersion ()
    return version;
...
```

basically I think this is the way you use UUID for primary keys.  I guess if this was going to work they would have documented this!

I'm sure I've heard it is possible though although my initial googling han't come up with anything so I thought I'd ask if anyone had done this before or could point me in the direction of a rough approach (I'm assuming it would be a bit deeper than my simple attempt) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the JPA spec doesn't allow for that. Time-based or number based. And you certainly would never have a generation strategy for one, since that is for PKs, and since the version is assigned directly by the JPA provider.

From the javadoc for `@Version`

> The following types are supported for version properties: int,
>   Integer, short, Short, long, Long, java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: But there is also a sentence n the documentation for @Version tag that says ‘The version column can be any kind of type, as long as you define and implement the appropriate UserVersionType.' ?  I've not used UserVersionType before so I'll look at that a bit more unless you know I'm on the wrong track...

Comment: That is not in the JPA spec, and neither is "UserVersionType". That is presumably Hibernate specific, non-portable. Go there and it's on your head. Since your question says "How to configure JPA" I answer for JPA.

Comment: fair point well made.  Ill accept the answer and open a hibernate specific question.